# Spring Data JPA - Create a dynamic Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to know if I can replace the @Query(value="") by @Query(value=query) where query is a String I can edit somewhere.

I have to create a function to search in my database using many details.

Here the code where I call my Repository :

```
    public List<FilteringRuleEto> findRuleByParam(FilteringRuleDto filteringRule) {

        String Query = "SELECT rule FROM FilteringRuleEto rule WHERE";

        if (!filteringRule.getRouteClass().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.routeClass LIKE ?1 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCodeOperator().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.codeOperator LIKE ?2 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCommercialTrunk().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.commercialTrunk LIKE ?3 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getSupportType().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.supportType LIKE ?4 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCalledNumber().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.calledNumber LIKE ?5 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCalledNumberRange().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.calledNumberRange = ?6 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCalledNumberWhitelist().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.calledNumberWhitelist = ?7 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCallingNumber().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.callingNumber LIKE ?8 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCallingNumberRange().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.callingNumberRange = ?9 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getCallingNumberWhitelist().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.callingNumberWhitelist = ?10 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getBeginDate().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.beginDate = ?11 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getEndDate().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.endDate = ?12 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getTgid().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.tgid LIKE ?13 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getFilteringType().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.filteringType LIKE ?14 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getDateInsert().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.dateInsert = ?15 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getEndDate().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.dateUpdate = ?16 AND";
        }
        if (!filteringRule.getComment().equals(null)) {
            Query += " rule.comment = ?17 AND";
        }
        Query.substring(0, Query.length() - 3); 

        //Here I want to send the String Query to the Repository
        
        return this.filteringRuleRepository.findRuleByParameters(
                filteringRule.getRouteClass(),
                filteringRule.getCodeOperator(),
                filteringRule.getCommercialTrunk(),
                filteringRule.getSupportType(),
                filteringRule.getCalledNumber(),
                filteringRule.getCalledNumberRange(),
                filteringRule.getCalledNumberWhitelist(),
                filteringRule.getCallingNumber(),
                filteringRule.getCallingNumberRange(),
                filteringRule.getCallingNumberWhitelist(),
                filteringRule.getBeginDate(),
                filteringRule.getEndDate(),
                filteringRule.getTgid(),
                filteringRule.getFilteringType(),
                filteringRule.getDateInsert(),
                filteringRule.getDateUpdate(),
                filteringRule.getComment()
        );

    }
```

In my Repository :

```
public interface FilteringRuleRepository extends JpaRepository<FilteringRuleEto, Integer> {

     
     @Query(value=theDynamicQuery)
     List<FilteringRuleEto> findRuleByParameters(String routeClass, String codeOperator, String commercialTrunk,
                                                 String supportType, String calledNumber, boolean calledNumberRange,
                                                 boolean calledNumberWhitelist, String callingNumber, boolean callingNumberRange,
                                                 boolean callingNumberWhitelist, OffsetDateTime beginDate, OffsetDateTime endDate,
                                                 String tgid, String filteringType, OffsetDateTime dateInsert, OffsetDateTime dateUpdate,
                                                 String comment);

}
```

The goal is to make the search as fast as possible. I don't want to use a query with 17 parameters when the user want to search in the data base with only 2 of them.

I followed this website to write my code :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

But I don't think the part 9 is what I looking for. Or maybe I missunderstood.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Using such code you breaking a lot of writing good code principles. Furthermore, the spring does not support dynamic queries. You can use the Criteria API in JPA. For example, you can write a method that requires a map or list of necessary parameters, and based on those parameters build your query. There also some popular ways to do dynamic queries such as QueryDSL and JPA Specifications.

Comment: @AndriiSyd The QueryDSL look's like what I'm looking for. I will search this way for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library called [spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa) to make it easier to implement dynamic queries with JPA.

You can use it to write the query templates. The query template will be built into different query strings before execution depending on your parameters when you invoke the method.

```java
public interface FilteringRuleRepository extends JpaRepository<FilteringRuleEto, Integer> {
    @DynamicQuery("select t from FilteringRuleEto t\n" +
        "<@where>\n" +
        "  <#if routeClass?has_content>\n" +
        "    and t.routeClass like :routeClass\n" +
        "  </#if>\n" +
        "  <#if codeOperator?has_content>\n" +
        "    and t.codeOperator like :codeOperator\n" +
        "  </#if>\n" +
        "  <#if commercialTrunk?has_content>\n" +
        "    and t.commercialTrunk like :commercialTrunk\n" +
        "  </#if>\n" +
        "</@where>"
    )
    List<FilteringRuleEto> findRuleByParameters(String routeClass, String codeOperator, String commercialTrunk,
                                                String supportType, String calledNumber, boolean calledNumberRange,
                                                boolean calledNumberWhitelist, String callingNumber, boolean callingNumberRange,
                                                boolean callingNumberWhitelist, OffsetDateTime beginDate, OffsetDateTime endDate,
                                                String tgid, String filteringType, OffsetDateTime dateInsert, OffsetDateTime dateUpdate,
                                                String comment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that ! It's exactly what I'm looking for. I have to ask if I can use it in my project but it's look like a good anwser.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in your project.